# Checkboxlist validation failing because length of list of checkboxes is always zero

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list and I'm trying to validate it so that the user should select at least one checkbox. For this checkbox list I'm binding the values from the database. This list is on a partial view.

```html
<div class="options" data-bind="foreach: User,
                                visible: true" style="display: none;">
  <input type="checkbox" 
         id="chk" 
         class='roles' 
         name='roles' 
         data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, 
                    checked:MyViewModel.MyData.UserCheckedValues" />
  <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
```

This is the code I tried for validating it:

```
   if ($('#chk input:checked').length > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please select atleast one technology')
        return false;
    }
```

However, every time I'm getting length 0 even when I select the checkbox. How can I validate this checkbox list?

Comment: You're looking for client side validation, yeah? Or is skipping client side validation and doing this with server side validation also an option?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with that bit of jQuery is probably because you specify the `id` property. However, that property must be unique (it's an *id* after all), and you are rendering checkboxes in an `foreach` so multiple elements will have `id="chk"`, which may cause all sorts of problems. In addition to that you seem to select `input`s inside the `chk` elements. Solving that will probably allow you to complete your current approach. See [the answer by @Origineil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103461/419956) for a way to solve this.

---

To provide an alternative, IMO a better way to tackle the problem you have utilizes the MVVM nature of Knockout. Implement the validness on your view model. The [Knockout-Validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) may be of help, but if you want to implement it yourself it shouldn't be too hard for simple cases.

You haven't provided a [full repro](http://sscce.org), so I need to make some assumptions about your View Model code. Here's what I imagine your situation should look like (with some stubs):

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.users = ko.observableArray([
        { Id: 1, Name: 'Rita' },
        { Id: 2, Name: 'Marcus' },
        { Id: 3, Name: 'Fido' }
    ]);

    self.selectedUsers = ko.observableArray();

    self.isUserSelectionInvalid = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.selectedUsers().length === 0;
    });
};
```

This makes validness a proper part of your view model. You can then bind to that in your View, and also use the validness property in things like [the `submit` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html)'s logic. For example:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: users, visible: true">
    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="chk" 
           class='roles'  
           name='roles'  
           data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, checked: $parent.selectedUsers" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
<span data-bind="visible: isUserSelectionInvalid" style="color: red;">Select at least one user</span>
<br />
<button data-bind="disable: isUserSelectionInvalid">Submit</button>
```

See all this in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rkysh/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to use `UserCheckedValues`. *I'm not familiar enough with the syntax of asp-mvc to provide that portion.*

---

But if you insist: `$('input:checkbox[id="chk"]:checked')` will work.

Do you really want the checkboxes to have the same id? I'd change that too.

```
<input type="checkbox" class='roles' name='roles' data-bind="value: Id, checked:MyViewModel.MyData.UserCheckedValues, attr:{id: 'chk' + $index() }" />
```

The selector would then need to match on "begins with":

```
$('input:checkbox[id^="chk"]:checked')
```

Answer (score -1):

validate in Controller ,

```
   [HttpPost]
    public string Index(IEnumerable<model> modelinstance)
   {
   if (modelinstance.Count(x => x.IsSelected) == 0)
    {
    return "You have not selected any City";
    }
    else
    {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("You selected - ");
    foreach (models model in modelinstance)
    {
        if (model .IsSelected)
        {
            sb.Append(model.Name + ", ");
        }
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
    return sb.ToString();
   }
   }
```

Comment: Validating server side as well is great, but I think the OP's question is about client side validation.

Comment: Actually i Cant see anything wch says tht OP's want Client Side validation , he just use JQuery tht does not  mean he want to validate only at client Side. 
if u find the reason ,  that OP's want Only Client Side Validation . let me know i ll remove this post